# how to release multiple alloc class?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Hi Im confusing how to release already aclloc class which dosen't store pointer from the header file. After the loop I lost my pointer to classes since it has all same instance name.

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
  MyClass *class = [[MyClass init]alloc];
   class.count = i;
  [classArray addObject:class];  
  [self addToScene:class];

}
```

I understand basic concept of memory alloc and retain but since I'm using cocos2d to programe, I'm not sure about the cause of the error is from Object-c or cocos2d. so I want to just make a clear idea about the dealing memory in object-c. help me:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Præ-scriptum: that alloc and init calls should be exchanged (allocate first, only then initialize).

You have to release them inside the loop - adding them to the array retains them.

```
for(i = 0;i < 20; i++) {
    MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    obj.count = i;
    [classArray addObject:obj];
    [obj addToScene:obj];
    [obj release];
}
```

Comment: Didn't Know Array retains object. haha Im such a noob, thanks!

Comment: @user842589 it's in the docs. :) Anyways, it wouldn't be logical otherwise, think a bit about it...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, store the objects in an `NSArray` and release them. Then after you're done with the objects release the array. This is one way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

The array retains its own contents, so you just have to make sure that you don't retain it, either:

```
// Simpler
{
    MyClass *c = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    ⋮
}
```

or:

```
// Less memory
{
    MyClass *c = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    ⋮
    [c release];
}
```

or even:

```
// Rely on ARC (simpler and less memory).
{
    MyClass *c = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    ⋮
}
```

**EDIT:** Credit to @H2CO3 for spotting the swapped alloc and init calls.

Comment: are you sure in the order of init and alloc?

Comment: @H2CO3: Thanks. I didn't even checked them; I just copy-pasted.

Comment: no problem :) I tend to spot these errors as they hurt... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look, when you add an **object to array**, its **reference count** increases by **1**, as array is referring to that object. So its a better to **release** that **allocated object after you add it to array**, or **mark it as autorelease when allocating**, so that all objects marked as **autorelease** will be selected for **garbage collection** at end of frame.

So try this,

```
MyClass *obj = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Or else this,

```
MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
....
....
[classArray addObject: obj];
[obj release];
```